# Using mod_rewrite to redirect all pages in folder on old domain to index of new domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all pages on an old site (wellnowwhat.net/nin/*.*) to the index of a new site (sykonaut.net/nin_old/). I only have access to the new site's .htaccess (the old site is owned by a friend), so I'm testing going the opposite direction. I can redirect the root (sykonaut.net) to his root (wellnowwhat.net) using mod_rewrite, but I cannot redirect my nin_old directory to his nin directory. I'm guessing I wouldn't be able to redirect the opposite direction, either. Here is [the entirety of] the code in my .htaccess:

```
AddHandler php5_2-wrap .php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sykonaut.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/nin_old(.*)$ http://www.wellnowwhat.net/nin [R,NC,L]
```

It does not work. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `.htaccess` in the `nin_old` directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /nin_old
RewriteRule ^.* http://www.wellnowwhat.net/nin/ [R,NC,L]
```

When you redirect to an external URL to a directory, I would add the trailing slash as this reduce an extra redirection.

Also when you test everything and it's all right, change `R` to `R=301` as this is preferred by most search engine for Permanent Redirection.

Comment: For whatever reason, this does not work. I now have an .htaccess in both the website root and nin_old, could that be the problem?

Comment: @electrickoolaid42 Try removing your `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sykonaut.net$ [NC]` I don't think this is needed anyway

Comment: Hrm. Progress. Now Firefox gives me this msg: The page isn't redirecting properly: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: @electrickoolaid42 Strange... do the two domains use the same server?? Or your old server `www.sykonaut.net` has already started redirecting?

Comment: The domains are on different servers, but I did send an old (non-working) set of lines for my friend to put in his .htaccess. I'll have him delete them now

Answer (score 0):

In apache 2.0 and higher, the prefix (leading "/") is removed from the URI before it's put through the rewrite engine for rules in the .htaccess file. Try removing the leading slash from your regular expression in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^nin_old(.*)$ http://www.wellnowwhat.net/nin [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference Jon. =/

Comment: @electrickoolaid42 what are the other rules in your htaccess? Are you sure they're not interferring? If I put these rules in an htaccess in my apache server, and request http://www.sykonaut.net/nin_old/blah it redirects me to http://www.wellnowwhat.net/nin